# How to save CFUUID in keychain

Tags: iphone, keychain, udid, sskeychain

I'm developing an iPhone application.
The application access some web service that aboug other things should recognize the device ID.

Since UDID is deprecated, I need to call CFUUIDCreate to generate my own UUID for this purpose.

The ID is security-sensitive: all my network communication is encrypted, and I don't want nobody but my certificate-authenticated server to know that UUID.
Besides, I want this identifier to survive re-install.
Using the keychain to store that UUID seems like an obvious solution.

How do I do that?

On the internets, there're some samples how to store user name & password in keychain. I have neither user nor password, just 16 bytes UUID (or a single NSString).

Which kSecClass do I need to use?
Which attributes do I need to set and retrieve?
Which attributes are optional and which are mandatory?

What header/framework defines the CSSM_ALGORITHMS?
The doc mentions cssmtype.h, xcode autocompletion has <Security/cssmtype.h> however the xcode compiler says "file not found".

From the common sense, "Identity" should fit best. The docs however say "an identity is the combination of a private key and a certificate", I have neither of them. Also, I don't see the "key bytes" attribute.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [SSKeychain](https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain) wrapper. Also check out the answer on this question for some basic usage stuff: 
[How to choose account and service values for SSKeychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663948/how-to-choose-account-and-service-values-for-sskeychain)