# How to retrive unique identification from iphone/ipad?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS hardware parameters for unique id generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689702/ios-hardware-parameters-for-unique-id-generation)

I need to identify uniquely the IOS device instead of requiring sign-up in order to uniquely identify the consumers of my app, this data will be send to our servers by consuming WCF service actions.

How can I identify that?

PS. IP is not an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDID (`[UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier;`) is deprecated, so i can't recommend you to use that...

What we do in our app is we generate a UUID and store it on the keychain, that together with a customer ID makes every "Profile" unique...

```
CFUUIDRef uuidObj = CFUUIDCreate(nil);//create the new UUID
NSString *uuidString = (NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(nil, uuidObj);
```

P.S. Beware that apple does not like you to tie a user to the device, so better be prepared to explain why you need this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be only supporting iOS6 you can use the UIDevice identifierForVendor.