# login and register using keychain

Tags: objective-c, xcode, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

I heard that using `keychain` is better than using `NSUserDefault`.
The problem is that I have no idea how to use it.
I'm trying to make a login and register for the users with all different passwords and usernames.
Can someone please demonstrate or screenshot the code for how to do it? oh and I'm using xcode 4.6

Comment: Find a wrapper. There are some already

Comment: do you mean through github?

Comment: Why don't you use SQLite, Core Data or anything to do with database?

Comment: @Goppinath I tried but I kept getting mach o-linker errors for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here can you find apple's KeyChainItemWrapper class: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Listings/Classes_KeychainItemWrapper_m.htm

You can use it like:

```
 KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"YourAppLogin" accessGroup:nil];

// Set the username and password using:
[keychainItem setObject:@"password you are saving" forKey:@"Password"];
[keychainItem setObject:@"username you are saving" forKey:@"Username"];

// Get them
 NSString *password = [keychainItem objectForKey:@"Password"];
 NSString *username = [keychainItem objectForKey:@"Username"];

// Delete them
[keychainItem resetKeychainItem];
```

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDeafults store data within the app and `Key-chain` stores data in iOS keychain.
You can use [SSKeyChain](https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain).
It's use easy and works with both ARC and Non-ARC.

Also check this [How to choose account and service values for SSKeychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663948/how-to-choose-account-and-service-values-for-sskeychain)